# УдилА, удить, удочка: однокоренные или нет?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Озадачивает слово "удила" (часть уздечки). Родственно ли оно словам "удочка", "удить"? По идее, ничего общего в значении слов нет, но звучит похоже.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удила- общеславянское, от праслав. udidlo > udilo - от глагола "удить" - вкладывать уду,где уда- крючок, металлич. звено узды.Образование праслав. уда - не вполне ясно.
Удочка, удить-собственно русское, др.-р. уда -снасть для ловли рыбы. Тоже восходит к праслав. уда, но объясняют его по-разному. Кто говорит, что у-это корень *on(крюк) + суфф. -d-, кто, что это приставка он- + корень, как в глаголе деть, положить, спрятать, т.е. уда - то, что приложено, как бы приставка.
В любом случае восходят к одному слову - уда. Значит, исторически родственны.